# Cannot find a Grails controller with 2 consecutive upper case letters

Tags: grails

I have created an controller named EBookController. When I start the Grails web application, the application returns a 404 on the eBook\index page.

I change the controller name to EbookController and applications works correctly when I request ebook\index.

Can Grails handle 2 or more consecutive upper case letters in the controller name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 8.8 of the spec at http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1470678357_57f26d616e55176cadc14024648f450c includes the following:

> However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, we
>   check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and
>   if so leave it alone.

That means `EBook` will map to `EBook` not `eBook`

Comment: Jeff, you were right. It was expecting EBook. Since we are using the REST services in GRAILS, I applied the following change to UrlMappings.groovy file which fixed the URL.

` "/api/$apiVersion/eBook"(resources: "EBool", excludes: [...])`

Answer (score 1):

Grail's handles the upper case controller names.

When it extract a property name from the middle of an existing Java name, it normally convert the first character to lower case.

However to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, it check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so leave it alone.

So in your case you can access your index action like below

```
EBook\index
```

If you want to access it with first character in small case then you will have to rename it to  `EbookController` as you have already tried.